# VB script to locate file

Tags: vbscript

I am requesting some help with a simple VB script I need to deploy to catch a few computers who only connect to my domain a few times a month and check for a file.

What I basically need is to see if a file is there. If it is.. Stop.

If not... Then look for a folder. If there, do this. Then stop. 
If not there, create folder and then do this.

This is what I have. I get and error on line 9 when the file is there and all I want is to stop the script.

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
If fso.FileExists("C:\output.log") Then
Else
    fso.CreateFolder("C:\temp") 
     fso.CopyFolder "\\DOMAIN\FOLDER", "c:\temp\FOLDER"
End If
If fso.FolderExists( "C:\temp") 
    fso.CopyFolder "\\DOMAIN\FOLDER", "c:\temp\FOLDER" 
Else
    fso.CreateFolder("C:\temp")
    fso.CopyFolder "\\DOMAIN\FOLDER", "c:\temp\FOLDER"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stick your script into a function or subroutine and then call that subroutine. Subroutines and functions can be exited:

```
Option Explicit

main

Sub main
    Dim fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
    If fso.FileExists("C:\output.log") Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        fso.CreateFolder("C:\temp") 
        fso.CopyFolder "\\DOMAIN\FOLDER", "c:\temp\FOLDER"
    End If
    If fso.FolderExists( "C:\temp") 
        fso.CopyFolder "\\DOMAIN\FOLDER", "c:\temp\FOLDER" 
    Else
        fso.CreateFolder("C:\temp")
        fso.CopyFolder "\\DOMAIN\FOLDER", "c:\temp\FOLDER"
    End If
End Sub
```

Your script will execute and the first thing you do is call the `main` sub. Which then runs and if the condition is right, exits. Since there are no more commands after we call `main` the script ends.

Comment: That's it!  Thanks!